# Strip ending set of parentheses from a string

Tags: ruby, regex

I've read [this][1] and [this][2], but they didn't quite answer my question.

Suppose I have the following product name & code:

`Cool Product 9000 (CP9000)`

I want to strip off the last space and everything after it to just be left with:

`Cool Product 9000`

How would I accomplish that?

And if you know of a guide or tutorial out there that would have explained this, feel free to just point me to that instead.

**EDIT: My apologies if my original question was slightly unclear. I appreciate all the answers, and I'll test them all to see which I like best before marking one as the answer.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same as OMG's approach but modifying `s` itself:

```
s = 'Cool Product 9000 (CP9000)'
s[s.rindex(' ')..-1] = ''

s
# => "Cool Product 9000"
```

Answer (score 5):

This should do:

```
string.sub!(/\s+\S*$/, '')
```

But, for parenthesized goodness, you can also do:

```
string.sub!(/\s+\(.*?$/, '')
```

and it will catch (and not catch) the examples given by @Phrogz below:

```
foo bar baz
```

will not be altered and

```
foo bar (bar baz)
```

will be turned into

```
foo bar
```

Comment: The OP said explicitly <<I want to strip off the last space and everything after it to just be left with>>

Comment: `+1`, as I don't love to guess beyond more whenever OP already mentioned his/her requirement.

Comment: My mistake, Massa. +1 :) I was misled by the disparity between the question title and sample data and that sentence. I have deleted my disparaging (and incorrect) comment.

Comment: While probably not the cleanest (but sure easy), couldn't ".split"ing the string into an array, deleting last element, then rejoining it work too? I thought about that after you answered.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = 'Cool Product 9000 (CP9000)'
s[0...s.rindex(" ")]
# => "Cool Product 9000"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
stripped = string.sub /\s*\([^)]+\)\z/, ''
```

That says:

- Find some optional whitespace `\s*`
- …followed by a literal open parenthesis `\(`
- …followed by one or more characters that are not a literal close parenthesis `[^)]+`
- …followed by a literal close parenthesis `\)`
- …followed by the end of the string `\z`

and replace it with nothing.

Comment: use the ungreedy-qualifier, Luke! `/\s*\(.*?\)\z/` :D

Comment: @Massa - That does the same thing but performs less well in general because of backtracking.